# Align equation to split equation or multiple split equations

Tags: align, split

I have a problem when trying to align multiple equations within the `align` environment if some (or all) of them are split into multiple lines with the `split` environment. For instance in the example below, I want all of the equal signs to align vertically, but it doesn't work because of the isc(t) in front of the second equal sign. If I remove that, the equal signs do align. I don't understand why it doesn't align, is there any way to fix this? I've added the code for the example below.

[image: example of misalignment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        i_3(t)&=\frac{V_3}{\omega_3L_3}e^{-\frac{R_3}{2L_3}t}\sin{\omega_3t}\\
        \begin{split}
        i_{sc}(t)&=i_1(t)+i_2(t)+i_3(t)\\
        &=\frac{V_1}{\omega_1L_1}e^{-\frac{R_1}{2L_1}t}\sin{\omega_1t}+\frac{V_2}{\omega_2L_2}e^{-\frac{R_2}{2L_2}t}\sin{\omega_2t}\\
        &\qquad+\frac{V_3}{\omega_3L_3}e^{-\frac{R_3}{2L_3}t}\sin{\omega_3t}\\
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton no:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{split}` is "aware" of the outer `{align}`'s alignment points, but you are ending the last line with `\\` which causes this issue. Just remove it and be happy.

As a personal preference I would use `{aligned}` for the last two lines, such that you don't have to introduce a manual `\qquad` there, but that's mostly a matter of taste. Note also that `\sin{\omega_3t}` isn't doing what you might think: `\sin` does not take an argument, so I would write it as `\sin(\omega_3t)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    i_3(t)&=\frac{V_3}{\omega_3L_3}e^{-\frac{R_3}{2L_3}t}\sin(\omega_3t)\\
    \begin{split}
    i_{sc}(t)&=i_1(t)+i_2(t)+i_3(t)\\
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
        &\frac{V_1}{\omega_1L_1}e^{-\frac{R_1}{2L_1}t}\sin(\omega_1t)+\frac{V_2}{\omega_2L_2}e^{-\frac{R_2}{2L_2}t}\sin(\omega_2t)\\
        &+\frac{V_3}{\omega_3L_3}e^{-\frac{R_3}{2L_3}t}\sin(\omega_3t)
       \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]